# Cron job fails to execute python script

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have set up a cron job that looks like this:

`* * * * * /full/path/to/venv/bin/python3 /full/path/to/main.py`

Python script itself writes logs to file and updates a BigQuery table.
Executing script from the terminal works fine, other cron jobs work fine except this one.

`grep CRON /var/log/syslog` output might be useful:

```
Mar 25 21:16:01 [comp_name] CRON[5618]: ([user_name]) CMD ([cron_job_command])
Mar 25 21:16:01 [comp_name] CRON[5617]: ([user_name]) MAIL (mailed 657 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

I'd be grateful for any assistance provided.

Comment: Are you sure it's being run as the correct user?

Comment: @TomKarzes how do I check that?

Comment: It depends on how you set up the cron job.  Is it in the system crontab?  Or your own personal crontab?

Comment: I'm setting it up with `crontab -e`

Comment: It should run as whoever you were logged in as when you ran `crontab -e`.

Comment: The job is producing some sort of output and cron is trying to email it to you, but this system isn't set up to handle email.  Instead, redirect standard output and standard error from the command into a file in your home directory.  Change the cron command to something like `/x/y/z/python3 /a/b/c/main.py  >/home/you/cron-output  2>&1` then after the job runs look for clues in the `cron-output` file

Comment: @ottomeister your comment was very helpful, I found an error, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone, but I was having difficulty launching a python script with Cron in Linux lite (Ubuntu). It worked fine in terminal. I realized I had gone in and changed the default launch program for the script file, in the properties, to my IDE [Atom]. I switched it back to Python and Cron job works like normal again. (Other scripts were working fine in Cron just this one wasn't executing.)